# Re ask location permission for flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, location

Using location package to get Realtime location of user. it asks just first time to allow permission but if user denies it. Its not asking for permission again.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that if the user denies the first time, the browser for default is denying forever (on the mobile application the user has two options: "denie" or "denied forever", if the user chooses "denie" you can try again, but if the user chooses to "denied forever" you will not be able to try again.) and so asking a second time will not work.

So the user will need to manually set the permission, on the browser they can go to the lock (if HTTPS) or the exclamation (HTTP) and then a dialog will appear with the location permission (if your app asked a first time).